# Is it true that AWS Lambda does not automatically load environment variables from a .env file? Why?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables

I uploaded my nodejs code to AWS as a lambda function. In the code files, there is a .env file containing environmental variables. One such variable is:

```
MyAPPTestVar=http://www.google.com
```

In the nodejs code, there is a line:

```
const x = process.env.MyAPPTestVar;
```

In the AWS Lambda function, will this variable be loaded successfully?

what is the value of `x`?  will it be undefined?

I know there are plenty of resources on AWS Documentation and stackoverflow about how to set up environment variables in AWS Lambda using the AWS console.  That is not my question.

I know how to set the environment variables in AWS Console.

The question is: Can I do it using just the .env file?

If not, why?

Comment: A .env file has no meaning unless you have code that explicitly parses and uses it. E.g. a library. By default no such library is there.

Comment: @luk2302  What is the library?  Since AWS Lambda is run in the Amazon Linux 2 operating system, I am assuming that the library exists in Ubuntu but not Amazon Linux 2. Can you confirm?

Comment: *You* would need to bundle whatever node library you want for that to take effect. Obviously stuff outside your code would not care about this at all, e.g. the node environment itself will not see anything of this. For all intents and purposes: use the lambda environment variables.

Comment: @luk2302  I am all settled with using the lambda environment variables. Just out of curiosity, I still don't quite get this: I have installed all node packages and those packages are uploaded with the code to the lambda function altogether. So why in the lambda function, vars in `.env` file cannot be loaded, but in local, they do get loaded?

Comment: Are you using the dotenv package to load values from the .env file? That's typically how you do [this](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/).